# I broke my Ubuntu and I can't get it up

Tags: grub2

I'm pretty much a newbie at this whole Linux thing. After some issues I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows a couple of weeks ago and moved all of my stuff there. Today I was trying to increase the size of my Ubuntu's partition through Windows and now whenever I try to load it it just goes straight to grub. I think the PC can't find the boot file. What can I do?
And if the OS itself is beyond saving, can I at least move some files out of it through a mounted CD?

Edit:
After running "sudo parted -l":

```
Model: ATA CT2000BX500SSD1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17.4kB  1066kB  1049kB               LDM metadata partition
 2      1066kB  16.8MB  15.7MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      16.8MB  2000GB  2000GB  ntfs         LDM data partition


Model: ADATA USB Flash Drive (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 15.5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  15.5GB  15.5GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba


Model: INTEL SSDPEKNW512G8 (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 512GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Warning: failed to translate partition name
Number  Start   End    Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  274MB  273MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      274MB   290MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      290MB   511GB  511GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 4      511GB   512GB  1153MB  ntfs                                       hidden, diag
```

Pictures of GParted:

[image: First]
[image: Second]
[image: Third]

Edit2: Found the solution - downloaded a program called TestDisk on my mounted CD and it found the broken partition. I am happy now.

Comment: Work with Windows partitions with Windows tools. Work with Ubuntu partitions with Ubuntu tools. You have messed up the partitions.

Comment: Windows does not understand the types of partitions (`ext4` or `zfs`) Ubuntu uses. They don't even show up as formatted partitions in Windows. Try booting from the Ubuntu Live Installation USB and use the **Try Ubuntu** option. Open Gparted and add a screenshot of the app (not the whole desktop) in your question. Alternately, here is a solution you may be familiar with from using Windows: **Reformat and Reinstall**.

Comment: Boot into Live Ubuntu, then run the command *sudo parted -l*. Paste the output into your question.

Comment: Ok, did everything you asked. Dunno if you'll get notified from this comment, but I'll try.

Comment: Please use something like @SmileytheSmile to make user a specific user is notified. You may use only one user at a time (in one comment).

Comment: @user68186 I can almost hear your annoyed sighs through the text.) Sorry, I'm new at this and kinda stressed out. Don't wanna lose some of the files I had in that Linux partition, but I guess I'll have to.

Comment: @PaulBenson Added the command results.

Comment: Re-sizing partitions is inherently risky, as you have discovered to your sorrow. All the gurus here strongly suggest backing up your beloved data before touching anything to do with partitions. It might be possible to recover some of your data before things get worse -- look for questions with the tag `data-recovery`

Comment: Please don't put the answer inside the question. This is a question answer site. You may answer your own question by clicking on the **Answer Your Own Question** button below. Please see the [site help on how to write a good answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer). A good answer will help others.